# Table coupling the product attributes and the orders in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-2.1, magento-1.8

Which table couples the orders and the product attributes of the related orders such as size, color and price?

For example, if my order contains a shirt, I need to get the color and size of the shirt through a query.

magento version 1.6.11

Comment: You have mentioned Magento 1.x and 2.x both. Please specify exact version to get better and specific answers.

Answer (score 0):

After submitting the a solution for serialized data, I did some digging, and came up with a query that (while containing a lot of scary-looking joins) should give you the information that you are looking for:

```
select 
    o.entity_id 'order_id', 
    qio.product_id, 
    qio.code 'option_id', 
    coptv.sku 'option_value'
from sales_flat_order o
join sales_flat_quote_item qi
    on o.quote_id = qi.quote_id
join sales_flat_quote_item_option qio
    on qi.item_id = qio.item_id
join catalog_product_option_type_value coptv
    on qio.value = coptv.option_type_id
where qio.code like 'option_%';
```

This may not be the most efficient way of selecting, and you may want to look at the other columns in the `catalog_product_option_title` table, as well as the four included above, but the output should be something like this:

```
order_id    product_id    option_id    option_value
---------------------------------------------------
1234        456          'option_78'   'WildCherry-Finish'
```

Comment: I need the result in unserialized format. Is there a any other table that I can refer to, to get these information about a product of a given order?

Comment: I updated the answer above.  Let me know if this works for you